# Oracle: True value in WHERE

Tags: sql, oracle

I am building a SQL query inside a function. The functions parameters are my criterias for the WHERE clause. Parameters can be null too.

```
foo (1,2,3)           =>   SELECT x FROM y WHERE a=1 AND b=2 AND c=3;
foo (null, 2, null)   =>   SELECT x FROM y WHERE b=2;
```

My approach to do that in code is to add a very first alltime true in the WHERE-clause (e.g. 1=1 or NULL is NULL or 2 > 1)

So I do not need to handle the problem that the 1st WHERE condition is after a "WHERE" and all others are after a "AND".

```
String sql="SELECT x FROM y WHERE 1=1";
if (a!=null)
{
  sql += " AND a="+a;
}
```

Is there a better term than 1=1 or my other samples to EXPLICITLY have a always true value? TRUE and FALSE is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle does not support a boolean type in SQL. It exists in PL/SQL, but can't be used in a query. The easiest thing to do is 1=1 for true and 0=1 for false. I'm not sure if the optimizer will optimize these out or not, but I suspect the performance impact is negligible. I've used this where the number of predicates is unknown until runtime.

I think this construct is superior to anything using `nvl`, `coalesce`, `decode`, or `case`, because those bypass normal indexes and I've had them lead to complicated and slow execution plans.

So, yes I'd do something like you have (not sure what language you're building this query in; this is not valid PL/SQL. Also you should use bind variables but that's another story):

```
sql = "SELECT x FROM y WHERE 1=1";
if (a != null)
{
    sql += " AND a=" + a;
}
if (b != null)
{
    sql += " AND b=" + b;
}
... etc.
```

I think this is better than Gordon Linoff's suggestion, because otherwise this would be more complicated because you'd have to have another clause for each predicate checking if there was a previous predicate, i.e. whether you needed to include the `AND` or not. It just makes the code more verbose to avoid a single, trivial clause in the query.

Comment: So that is exactly what I hat in my question - but I asked for a better term for always TRUE instead of 1=1.

Answer (score 3):

I've never really understood the approach of mandating a `where` clause even when there are no conditions.  If you are constructing the logic, then combine the conditions.  If the resulting string is empty, then *leave out the `where` clause* entirely.

Many application languages have the equivalent of `concat_ws()` -- string concatenation with a separator (`join` in Python, for instance).  So leaving out the `where` clause does not even result in code that is much more complicated.

As for your question, Oracle doesn't have boolean values, so `1=1` is probably the most common approach.

Comment: That's actually the problem.  Either there is a where which applies if there is a condition but only once, or there isn't.  The actual "solution" would be to allow the where , but not mandate a condition.  But thanks for the note about 1=1; I was surprised that booleans were allowed, but there was no boolean literal - my *actual* reason coming to this question.

Answer (score 1):

use NVL so you can set a default value. Look up NVL or NVL2. Either might work for you.
check out: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_nvl_vs_nvl2.htm

Answer (score 0):

In sql the standard way to "default null" is to use coalesce.  So lets say your input is @p1, @p2, and @p3

Then

```
 select *
 from table
 where a = coalesce(@p1,a) and 
       b = coalesce(@p2,b) and 
       c = coalesce(@p3,c)
```

Thus if (as an example) @p1 is null then it will compare a = a (which is always true).  If @p1 is not null then it will filter on a equals that value.

In this way null becomes a "wildcard" for all records.

Answer (score 0):

you could also use decode to get the results you need since it is oracle

```
Select 
decode(a, 1, x,null),
decode(b, 2, x,null),
decode(c, 3, x,null)
from y
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using `OR` inside of the parentheses while `AND`s exist at outside of them

```
SELECT x 
  FROM y 
 WHERE ( a=:prm1 OR :prm1 is null) 
   AND ( b=:prm2 OR :prm2 is null) 
   AND ( c=:prm3 OR :prm3 is null);
```